# <dom-if> in <dom-repeat> doesn't call method on item change

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to make a text show or not based on conditions called in a function.

I have the following snippet :

```
<dom-module id="lfr-defis">
<template>
    <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment"></style>
    <style is="custom-style">
        h4{
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        paper-card{
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        p{
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <paper-icon-button icon="add" on-tap="newDefi" style="float: right"></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 5px">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[defis]]">
            <paper-card style="width: 100%">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="layout horizontal">
                        <paper-input label="Jeu" class="flex" always-float-label value="{{item.gameName::change}}"></paper-input>
                        <div style="margin:5px"></div>
                        <paper-input label="Incentive" class="flex" always-float-label value="{{item.incentiveName::change}}"></paper-input>
                    </div>
                    <label for="datetime"><b>Date : </b></label><datetime-input id="datetime" value="{{item.date::change}}"></datetime-input>
                    <h4>Défi FR</h4>
                    <div class="layout horizontal justified">
                        <paper-input value="{{item.fr.name::change}}" class="flex">
                            <iron-icon icon="label" slot="prefix"></iron-icon>
                        </paper-input>
                        <div style="margin:5px"></div>
                        <paper-input value="{{item.fr.amount::change}}" type="number">
                            <div slot="prefix">$ </div>
                        </paper-input>
                        <div style="margin:5px"></div>
                        <paper-input value="{{item.fr.rank::change}}" type="number">
                            <iron-icon icon="editor:format-list-numbered" slot="prefix"></iron-icon>
                        </paper-input>
                    </div>

                    <h4>Concurrent direct</h4>
                    <div class="layout horizontal justified">
                        <paper-input value="{{item.concurrent.name::change}}" class="flex">
                            <iron-icon icon="label" slot="prefix"></iron-icon>
                        </paper-input>
                        <div style="margin:5px"></div>
                        <paper-input value="{{item.concurrent.amount::change}}" type="number">
                            <div slot="prefix">$ </div>
                        </paper-input>
                        <div style="margin:5px"></div>
                        <paper-input value="{{item.concurrent.rank::change}}" type="number">
                            <iron-icon icon="editor:format-list-numbered" slot="prefix"></iron-icon>
                        </paper-input>
                    </div>

                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!hasAllFields(item)}}">
                        <p style="color:red">Tous les champs doivent être renseignés</p>
                    </template>
                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!validRank(item.fr.rank, item.concurrent.rank)}}">
                        <p style="color:red">Un des rangs doit être égal à 1</p>
                    </template>
                    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!validAmount(item.fr.rank, item.concurrent.rank, item.fr.amount, item.concurrent.amount)}}">
                        <p style="color:red">Le montant du 1er doit être supérieur à l'autre</p>
                    </template>
                </div>
                <div class="card-actions">
                    <paper-icon-button title="Sauvegarder" icon="save" on-tap="save" data-item$="{{item}}" style="color:deepskyblue"></paper-icon-button>
                    <paper-icon-button title="Annuler" icon="cancel" on-tap="cancel" data-item$="{{item}}" style="color:lightcoral"></paper-icon-button>
                    <paper-icon-button title="Supprimer" icon="delete" on-tap="delete" data-item$="{{item}}" style="float:right"></paper-icon-button>
                    <paper-icon-button title="Archiver" icon="archive" on-tap="archive" data-item$="{{item}}" style="float:right; color:gray"></paper-icon-button>
                </div>
            </paper-card>
        </template>
    </div>

</template>


<script src="defis.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

Javascript :

```
class Defis extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
        return 'lfr-defis';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            defis: {
                type: Array,
                value: []
            }
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    newDefi() {
        this.push('defis', {
            id: + new Date(),
            date: + new Date(),
            fr: {},
            concurrent: {}
        });
    }

    save(event) {
        const item = this.getItem(event);
        const index = this.defis.findIndex(d => d.id === item.id);
        if(index !== -1){
            this.defis[index] = item;
        }
        else{
            this.push('defis', item);
        }
    }

    cancel(event) {
        const item = this.getItem(event);
        const index = this.defis.findIndex(d => d.id === item.id);
        if(index !== -1){
            this.set('defis.' + index, item);
        }
    }

    delete(event) {
        const item = this.getItem(event);
        const index = this.defis.findIndex(d => d.id === id);
        this.splice('defis', index, 1);
    }

    archive(event) {
        const item = this.getItem(event);
        const index = this.defis.findIndex(d => d.id === id);
        this.splice('defis', index, 1);
    }

    getItem(event) {
        return JSON.parse(event.target.dataset.item);
    }

    hasAllFields(item, trigger) {
        return item.gameName && item.incentiveName && item.date &&
            item.fr.name && item.fr.amount && item.fr.rank &&
            item.concurrent.name && item.concurrent.amount && item.concurrent.rank;
    }

    validRank(rankA, rankB) {
        return rankA && rankA === '1' || rankB && rankB === '1';
    }

    validAmount(rankA, rankB, amountA, amountB) {
        return rankA > rankB && parseInt(amountA) < parseInt(amountB) ||
            rankA < rankB && parseInt(amountA) > parseInt(amountB) ||
            rankA === rankB && parseInt(amountA) === parseInt(amountB);
    }

    isValid(item) {
        return this.hasAllFields(item) && this.validRank(item.fr.rank, item.concurrent.rank) &&
            this.validAmount(item.fr.rank, item.concurrent.rank, item.fr.amount, item.concurrent.amount);
    }
}

customElements.define(Defis.is, Defis);
```

The problem I have is that the `hasAllFields(item)` function is called only once on page load, and not when I change the values in my `<paper-input>` fields (which would be the expected behaviour). Therefore, since the function returns `false` on load, the message is shown, however it is never updated, thus doesn't hide when all my fields are filled.

I've seen that it might be related to the use of the `item` element in a `<dom-repeat>` but I couldn't find any solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Polymer to update subproperties in DOM, then you need to add those subproperties to the method call. Polymer isn't smart enough to understand when subproperies are updated.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{!hasAllFields(item.gameName, item.incentiveName, tem.date, item.fr.name, item.fr.amount, item.fr.rank, ), item.concurrent.name, item.concurrent.amount, item.concurrent.rank}}">
```

Another way is to add an observer, that checks the same properties as above, that updates an int property every time the properties change, and then you pass that int into `hasAllFields`, for example `hasAllFields(inputUpdatedInt)`. A third way would be to add an listener on input and then do a hard reset on debris with `this.set('debris', []` before setting the new values because that will actually change `item` that you're checking against now.

Comment: The first solution is what I ended up doing. Quite verbose, but it gets the job done. I might try some other solutions the day I'll need to refactor this.

Comment: When it comes to clarity, I prefer the first way. Observers and listeners makes it hard to understand when is what executed when you read the code.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your method to pass also item.gameName

```
hasAllFields(item,item.gameName)
```

change also your function to have one more parameter even if  you won't  use it

practically **Polymer** does not  detect changes in the object item but it should in the sub properties

One more point, you might need 
`value="{{item.gameName::input}}"` or `value="{{item.gameName::change}}"`

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you. However, I simplified the example here, as I have a total of 9 fields in my item. Should I put all of them in the parameters ?

Comment: have all parameters  should not change so much, however is always better have the closest code to simulate the issue.

Comment: one more thing, basically if  you want to trigger the function when a specific parameter or parameters change you to put them in the function, but just the parameters which you want to specifically to trigger the function

Comment: I've put `::change` at the end of all my fields, and changed the validation methods to take all the necessary parameters instead of the `item` object. It works this way. However, the hack you suggested to put `item,item.gameName` as the parameters did not work. I would still like to find a solution for the `hasAllFields` function because I want to avoid passing all parameters one by one.

Comment: I see, so you need to trigger the function when any of your input field change value.. I might have a better  solution but I need to se the more html, can you update to see which the container of your repeater?